# SHA Encryption in iOS

Tags: android, swift, kotlin, encryption, sha

I have this code on Android:

```
val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512")
digest.update("secretotpkey".toByteArray())

val sb = StringBuilder()
val bytes = digest.digest(value.toByteArray())
bytes.forEach {
    sb.append(((it and 0xF) + 0x100).toString(16).substring(1))
}

val encryptedValue = sb.toString()
makeLog("Encrypted value is $encryptedValue")
return encryptedValue
```

I am trying to convert this to iOS by using CryptoSwift. However I am getting different results. Any ideas how to fix?

```swift
var digest = Digest.sha512("secretotpkey".bytes)
print(digest)
let bytes = "54181474".bytes
print(bytes)
digest.append(contentsOf: bytes)
var blah = String()
for item in digest {
    let a = Int(item & 0xF) + Int(0x100)
    let b = (String(format:"%02X", a)).substring(range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 2))
    print(b)
    blah.append(b)
}
```

Comment: SHA-512 is a cryptographic hash, it's not encryption. By the way, always indicate the runtimes in the tags. You can unindent your code using the code button on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Two encoding issues:

1. you're not indicating the characters set when converting the key to bytes (a key should consist of bytes in the first place, strings are not keys).
2. your hex encoding is clearly not correct for either Kotlin or Swift; please use a pre-made library call instead or look up correct code here on StackOverflow.

That should fix it, because there is nothing there but a call to a standardized algorithm, SHA-512 otherwise.